# Filtering TableView with array in array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have 2 methods:

```
class Sign {

    let code: String

    let name: String

    let description: String

    let picture: String

    

    init(code: String, name: String, description: String, picture: String) {

        self.code = code

        self.name = name

        self.description = description

        self.picture = picture

    }

}

class Category {

    let name: String

    let sign: [Sign]

    

    init(name: String, sign: [Sign]) {

        self.name = name

        self.sign = sign

    }

}
```

Both are used to be in TableView - Category as section title and Sign as section row. I tried to implement searchBar above tableView, but when I start type keyword I see only Category names filtered. Do you have any idea how to figure out that?

Eg.

```
var categories: [Category] = [

        Category(name: "X", sign: [Sign(code: "X-1", name: "***"),
        Category(name: "Y", sign: [Sign(code: "Y-1", name: "Yyy"),
```

After typing "yy" || "y" in search bar I need my tableView shows only Sign which contains "yy".

My current TableView configuration:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredCategories.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredCategories[section].sign.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return filteredCategories[0].name

    case 1:
        return filteredCategories[1].name

    case 2:
        return filteredCategories[2].name

    case 3:
        return filteredCategories[3].name

    default:
        return "Error"
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PropertyKeys.categorieCell, for: indexPath) as! SignTableViewCell

    let categorie = filteredCategories[indexPath.section]

    let sign = categorie.sign[indexPath.row]

    cell.signImagemin.image = UIImage(named: sign.picture)

    cell.signCodeMin.text = sign.code

    cell.signDescriptionMin.text = sign.name

    return cell
}
```

My current searchBar func:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    
    filteredCategories = []
    let text = searchText.lowercased()
    
    if searchText == "" {
        filteredCategories = categories
    } else {
        for categorie in categories {
            if categorie.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                let signs = categorie.sign.filter() { $0.name.contains(searchText) }
                let newCat = categorie
                newCat.sign = signs
                
                filteredCategories.append(newCat)
            }
        }
    }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thank you!

Eg.: In this tableView [clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4m6H.png)

Want to see only signs which contain "A1" and Cat A above as section name
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KO31.png)

Comment: Do you want to search only in the sign name?  Currently you are also searching in the category name.

Comment: I would like to search only sign name, but with row titles visible

Comment: If you only want to search sign name then why are you testing to see if the category name contains your search text? (Get rid of the if statement `if categorie.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())`.)

Answer (score 0):

You just control the `categorie.name` contains the giving search keyword.You must add also this `categorie.sign.filter({$0.name.contains(searchText)}).count != 0` to your if condition. It will be like

```
if categorie.sign.filter({$0.name.contains(searchText)}).count != 0{ 
// codes here

}
```

Also you declared `sign` in `Category` class with `let` so

```
let newCat = categorie
newCat.sign = signs
```

Above code is illegal You need to change `let` with `var` in class
`Category`

```
 var sign: [Sign]
```

Comment: Almost done, but now It's look like newCat overwrited my original var category instead of filteredCategories, and after searchBar is empty again I see filtered match positions and full list from array when text doesn't match - mix of categories and filtered categories.

Comment: To the OP: You should not be saving your filtered arrays of signs back to your original array of categories. You need to create a new array `filteredCategories` that contains filtered arrays of signs, and leave the original array of categories alone.

Comment: Omer, I don't think the OP wants to filter categories by category name, so your first if statement should probably read `if categorie.sign.filter({$0.name.contains(searchText)}).count != 0 {` (Get rid of the test that the category name contains the search text.)

Comment: you are right i fixed it now @DuncanC

Comment: Duncan, Yes I have it under my original array "var filteredCategories: [Category]!" So how can I load the filtered data to this one if newCat refer to the original one